# Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:8000 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

I'm trying to install `dynamodb` locally for **docker**.

I've written the below code from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/).

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedD
```

Then I can reach `localhost:8000/shell`

In my client **java**, I set the endpoint

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
    .withEndpointConfiguration(
        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000/", "eu-central-1")
    ).build();
```

but when I run it, log the following error.

Can anyone help me? enter code here

Comment: Is the client running directly on the host, or in a separate container?

Comment: run on same host

Answer (score 5):

Replace your endpoint configuration from:

```
http://localhost:8000
```

To:

```
http://host.docker.internal:8000
```

Comment: It only works on Mac. On Linux this http://host.docker.internal:8000 is not reachable and requires extra steps https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/how-to-connect-to-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container-112b4c71bc66